# How to run this Terminal line in Automator's Run Shell Script?

Tags: macos, shell, automator

I am a Terminal newbie and installed aria2 on my Mac. When I need to use aria2, I open up Terminal and enter "aria2c" without touching anything else, it works great.

[image: Using Terminal]

Then I want to create an application to run this line with Automator so I can just drop it to the dock and click to start aria2. I tried but no luck, any help please!

[image: Automator]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the following:

/usr/local/aria2/bin/aria2c